# Hide All Descendent Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with jQuery in trying to toggle the children tr's of a parent tr.
This is working for one tr level at a time; however, when an inner tr collapses its children and then the outer one does the same, the children of the inner tr remain visible.
I want all descendents (the Level 2 and Level 3 classes) to be hidden when the Level 1 class is clicked, and I want the Level 3 class to be hidden when the Level 2 class is clicked.

Here's the code I've been using.

```
$(".mainTable td[class^='Level1']").each(function() {
    //copy td class to tr
    $(this).parent().addClass($(this).attr('class'));
    //add function to tr
    $(this).parent().click(function() {
        //toggle all elements to next Level1 class
        $(this).nextUntil("[class^='Level1']").toggle();
    });
});


$(".mainTable td[class^='Level2']").each(function() {
    //copy td class to tr
    $(this).parent().addClass($(this).attr('class'));
    //add function to tr
    $(this).parent().click(function() {
        //toggle all elements to next Level1 class
        $(this).nextUntil("[class^='Level1']").toggle();
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<table class="mainTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td class="Level1">Level 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="Level1">Level 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="Level2">Level 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="Level3">Level 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="Level1">Level 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="Level1">Level 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="Level2">Level 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you modify the HTML or it has to stay like this?

Comment: Table rows don't have children or parent rows, rows are all siblings of each other. The parent of the row is the table. Use .prev() or .next instead of .parent()

Answer (score 1):

You can make this code more DRY. This should work for any levels depth. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/zd9DQ/).

```
function getLevel(el) { //extract level as integer from classname
    var level = /Level(\d+)/.exec(el.className)
    return level != null ? parseInt(level[1], 10) : NaN;    
}

$('.mainTable').on('click', 'td', function() { //use event delegation
    var level = getLevel(this), //get current level
        parent, state;
    if(level == level) { //checking for NaN              
        parent = $(this).parent('tr'); //get parent
        state = !!parent.data('state'); //get current state

        parent.nextUntil(function(_, item) { //filter lower levels
                    return getLevel(item.cells[0]) <= level;
               })
              .each(function(_, item) {
                    $(item).data('state', !state)
                           .toggle(state);
               }); //show|hide

        parent.data('state', !state); //save current state.
    }
});
```

If you can modify html you can greatly reduce code complexity by using data attributes.

```
<tr data-level="1">...</tr>
<tr data-level="3">...</tr>
```

Specifying levels like this you will eliminate all the string manipulations required to extract level in a form of number.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
$(".mainTable td[class^=Level]").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass($(this).attr('class'));
});

$(".mainTable tr[class^=Level1]").click(function() {
    var items = $(this).nextUntil("[class^=Level1]");

    if (items.filter(':hidden').length > 0) {
        items.show();
    }
    else {
        items.hide();
    }
});

$(".mainTable tr[class^=Level2]").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil("[class^=Level1], [class^=Level2]").toggle();
});
```

Demo here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq2B7/1/)

Comment: thanks - the only problem is that when I click on level 2, the level3 class underneath it does not remain collapsed when the next up level1 class is clicked.

Comment: thanks.  this is definitely getting there.  the only problem now is that when I click on Level 2 above Level 3 to hide Level 3, and then I click on Level 1, Level 3 reappears on the first click of Level 1.  When I click Level 1 again, both Level 2 and Level 3 disappear (which is the behaviour I desire in this).